# Batch Image Resizing / Scaling

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to scale my images in .bat. For Example,

```
900
[  ] 600
```

I want to set the 900 pixel height to 400, then readjust the 600 to a percentage so it'll be a good quality and equal to the 900x600. I also want the batch file to automatically adjust the bigger size to be set as a pixel. Is this possible?

Whenever I try searching, I only find converting images through a batch through photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I really understand you question. Save this code as a .bat file then drag and drop your image over the batch file icon.

```
convert "%1" -thumbnail 400x -unsharp 1.5x1.2+1.0+0.10 "%~p1resized_%~n1.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this free tool, it has been around for long, don't know if works in any Windows version. 
http://www.rw-designer.com/picture-resize